# Include or forward declare a header struct in IDL for C++

Tags: c++, windows, idl

I have a header file (special.h) that includes the following struct:

```
typedef struct SPECIAL_STRUCT{
    UINT x;
    UINT y;
} SPECIAL_STRUCT;
```

And I'd like to include this struct as the input parameter of a function in an IDL file that defines test interfaces (test.idl):

```
interface ITestInterface : IUnknown
{        
    void* GetData(
        SPECIAL_STRUCT Special,
        UINT Data);
};
```

What's the right way to do this? It sounds like I can do one of the following:

- According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, I can "use the import directive to include data types defined in a header file." However, what's the syntax for doing that? I have tried the following:

  import "special.h" // error MIDL2025 : syntax error : expecting an interface name or DispatchInterfaceName or CoclassName or ModuleName or LibraryName or ContractName or a type specification near "DEFINE_GUID"
- Also according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, I can "create a helper IDL file with a dummy interface that includes the header files." However, I prefer not to do this since I just need a single struct definition.
- I also tried forward delcaring the struct in the IDL, i.e.

  typedef struct SPECIAL_STRUCT; //error MIDL2312 : illegal syntax unless using mktyplib compatibility mode : SPECIAL_STRUCT

  struct SPECIAL_STRUCT; //error MIDL2025 : syntax error : expecting a type specification near SPECIAL_STRUCT

I realize this might be a newbie IDL question, but I'd definitely apprecaite feedback. Thanks!

Comment: One common way, the "other" header itself is part and parcel with its *own* IDL, which, when compiled, creates its own .h file. In the mean time, *your* IDL imports that IDL and, handy enough when your .h is generated, it automagically includes a `#include "other.h"` to pull in the proper header. You could equally compile it to a type lib an import that. As I said, there are numerous ways. Interesting things happen when  custom *marshalling* is needed for this, btw. Read more about the import directive [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367047(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: That sounds like my second option above? I am not sure it's worth the effort to wrap a header (.h) in its own IDL file just for this...